# No such file or directory:

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to read a lot of excel files from a directory. When I run the following code, it gives me this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '35TP2_TR1.xlsx'
```

Code:

```
#GUI
root=Tk()
root.withdraw() #closes tkinter window pop-up
path=filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root,title='Choose a folder')
path=path+'/'

print('Folder Selected',path)
files=os.listdir(path)
print(files)
length=len(files)

print('Files inside the folder',files)

data=[None]*length  

for s in range(0,length):
    data[s]=pd.read_excel(files[s],parse_cols="A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O",skiprows=2)
```

this way, I was reading from the local folder, which is why it couldn't find the file. 
Thanks.

Comment: `data[s] = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(path, files[s]), ......`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like it says, `35TP2_TR1.xlsx` is not a file or a directory, because the script can't find it from the relative path (i.e the script is not located in the same folder than the .xlsx file).

You could try `os.path.abspath(file[s])` to get the absolute path of the file.